# Why does my class polymorphism fail (C++)

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I want to return a **struct** which uses a number and one object deriving from one of **3 subclasses** that tell the method where to add the number. My thought process is that using *runtime polymorphism*, I can **overload** the method and have the sum of different sub classes in 3 variables. However this doesn't seem to happen because the object **doesn't get casted down to it's child class**. Bear in mind, that the program doesn't know beforehand which subclass will be the struct, **so manual casting is not possible**.

The class with the subclasses (s.h):

```
#pragma once

class Sugar{};

class Nincs : public Sugar
{
     private:
        static Nincs* ins;
        Nincs(){};
    public:
        static Nincs* instance();
};

class Alfa : public Sugar
{
    private:
        static Alfa* ins;
        Alfa(){};
    public:
        static Alfa* instance();
};

class Delta : public Sugar
{
    private:
        static Delta* ins;
        Delta(){};
    public:
        static Delta* instance();
};
```

The class with the subclasses (s.cpp):

```
#include "s.h"

Nincs* Nincs::ins = nullptr;
Alfa* Alfa::ins = nullptr;
Delta* Delta::ins = nullptr;

Nincs* Nincs::instance()
{
    if (ins == nullptr)
    {
        ins = new Nincs();
    }

    return ins;
};

Alfa* Alfa::instance()
{
    if (ins == nullptr)
    {
        ins = new Alfa();
    }

    return ins;
}

Delta* Delta::instance()
{
    if (ins == nullptr)
    {
        ins = new Delta();
    }

    return ins;
}
```

The classes that return the struct (this is only n.h for now, I plan to separate it into .h and .cpp once this issue is resolved):

```
#pragma once

#include "s.h"

struct Sugarzas
{
    Sugar* fajta;
    int mennyiseg;
};

class Noveny
{
    protected:
        std::string nev;
        int tapanyag;
        bool el_e;
    public:
        Noveny(std::string v1, int v2, bool v3): nev(v1), tapanyag(v2), el_e(v3){}
        virtual Sugarzas ker(){};
};

class Puffancs : public Noveny
{
    public:
        Puffancs(std::string v1, int v2, bool v3): Noveny(v1,v2,v3){};
        Sugarzas ker() override
        {
            Sugarzas s;
            s.fajta = Alfa::instance();
            s.mennyiseg = 10;

            return s;
        }
};


class Deltafa : public Noveny
{
    public:
        Deltafa(std::string v1, int v2, bool v3): Noveny(v1,v2,v3){};
        Sugarzas ker() override
        {
            Sugarzas s;
            s.fajta = Delta::instance();
            if (tapanyag < 5)
            {
                s.mennyiseg = 4;
            }
            else if (tapanyag >=5 && tapanyag <=10)
            {
                s.mennyiseg = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                s.mennyiseg = 0;
            }

            return s;
        }
};


class Parabokor : public Noveny
{
    public:
        Parabokor(std::string v1, int v2, bool v3): Noveny(v1,v2,v3){};
        Sugarzas ker() override{}
};
```

main file with the functions:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "s.h"
#include "n.h"

using namespace std;

int sumNincs, sumAlfa, sumDelta;

void addTo(Nincs* s, int x)
{
    sumNincs += x;
}

void addTo(Alfa* s, int x)
{
    sumAlfa += x;
}

void addTo(Delta* s, int x)
{
    sumDelta += x;
}

int main()
{
    Puffancs* n = new Puffancs("bob",5,true);

    sumNincs = 0;
    sumAlfa = 0;
    sumDelta = 0;


    Sugarzas s = n->ker();

    addTo(s.fajta,s.mennyiseg); //s.fajta comes out as Sugar* and does not get casted to the subclasses

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look up abstract classes, or base class pointer, for a good starting point.

Comment: **Polymorphism** uses `virtual` to signify the *polymorphic* method.  Polymorphic objects are handled using pointers or reference, because a concrete type (likely to the base class) will slice.  The `addTo` isn't "working" because the type of the pointer is `Puffancs*` which doesn't match.  And `s` has been sliced to a `Sugarzas`.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like there's some confusion between function overloading and function overriding. Virtual functions can be *overridden*, where a member function defined in a base class can be overridden by a member function with the same signature* in a derived class, and then calls to the base class method will be dispatched based on the actual runtime most derived class of the object the methods are being called on.

*Except possibly having a covariant return type.

---

However, your `addTo` functions are not a case of overriding. They are a case of overloading, where you have functions with the same name but different signatures. Overload resolution must be resolved at compile time. The static type of `s.fajta` is `Sugar*`, even though the actual pointed-to object is an `Alfa`.

You'd need your `Sugar` class to have virtual methods if you want to be able to have behavior that depends on the concrete type of `*s.fajta`. Since I'm not clear on what exactly is supposed to be happening here, I'm not sure how to restructure your program to use this behavior.